# No access to Program Files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-administration

I'm totally new to windows 7 and have just installed Apache server. I want to change httpd file... But when opening file with notepad and saving it, I get a message that I have no rights... My user is a member of Administrators group. What else can I do?

Thanks

P.S. Could you suggest any nice tutorials on dealing with user administration and admin accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take ownership of the folder, which requires a registry hack. (You can search for takeown registry)

My advice is to install your Apache server outside of "Program Files". You should not have files requiring regular modifications in Program Files.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try a different editor, say NotePad++. Run in Administrator. Also make sure that Apache is not running and any related tasks are shut down. Try it in Safe Mode if you get desperate.

Comment: Cool, launching it from MenuStart->Run with ctrl+shift (as admin) worked fine. Anyway, is there a way to make my account work in "Run as admin" context all the time?

Comment: The best I could find for files was to create a shortcut and in Properties>Compatibility set it to run in admin. The same will work for an executable. http://mintywhite.com/vista/vsecurity/always-run-a-program-as-administrator-howto/

Comment: Thx. But when I did it for notepad++ I get error message :Notepad++ extension error. Error in create process. Is this command correct?....

Comment: Hmm. Maybe turn off the plugins in Notepad++?

Comment: Yeah, it's something to do with plugins... Anyway thx for advice.